# StringTemplate4 :: template call inside template call

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I am trying to call a template, passing as a parameter the result of calling another template but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's a narrow-down example:

The following template group in a file:

```
echo(foo) ::="<foo>"
boo() ::= << <echo("zoo")> >>
```

When called with the following Java code:

```
STGroup stg = new STGroupFile("thefile.stg");
ST boo = stg.getInstanceOf("boo");
System.out.println(boo.render());
```

produces **zoo** as expected.

However, when I try to replace the **"zoo"** literal with a template that return the same, **ST** complains during parsing:

#### doesn't work:

```
echo(foo) ::="<foo>"
zoo() ::= "zoo"
boo() ::= << <echo( <zoo()>  )> >>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
boo() ::= << <echo( <zoo()> )> >>
```

use:

```
boo() ::= << <echo(zoo())> >>
```

It appears that the < > need only be used once where the outer template is called.